# Checking if one NSDate is greater than another

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

```
if (datStartDate > datEndDate) {
```

This doesn't seem to work. I know there's a `isEqual`, etc., but how do I perform "is greater than"?

There are both `NSDate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two NSDates: Which is more recent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The easiest method i'm aware is:

```
if( [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate] > 0 ) {
```

The other answers cover compare:, wanted to add some flavour ;).

Comment: No reason to use this idea because we have -compare: method. But idea is working one for sure.

Comment: A one-liner is big enough reason to use it. +1.

Comment: this does have a an appeal (and flavour) But I think it may return wrong answer for very close NSDates, because of  float-calculation and comparison accuracy issues. Better use the 'compare:' or add a more readable semantic wrapper -(BOOL) isEarlierThan: and -(BOOL) isLaterThan: to the existing -(BOOL)isEqual:

Answer (score 32):

To compare dates use `-compare:` method:

> Return Value If:
>
> - The receiver and anotherDate are
>     exactly equal to each other,
>     **NSOrderedSame**
> - The receiver is later in
>     time than anotherDate,
>     **NSOrderedDescending**
> - The receiver is
>     earlier in time than anotherDate,
>     **NSOrderedAscending**.

Answer (score 20):

What about...

```
if ([datStartDate earlierDate: datEndDate] == datStartDate) {
    // datStartDate is earlier
} else {
    // datEndDate is earlier
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 13):

As you have [NSDates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDate *datStartDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-10-01 03:00:00 +0900"];
NSDate *datEndDate   = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-10-01 04:00:00 +0900"];

if ( ([datStartDate compare:datEndDate]) == NSOrderedDescending ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Constructing strings with 'natural language' is now fully deprecated and this will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2 version of accepted answer:

```
if firstDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(secondDate) > 0 {
    // firstDate is greater (further in the future) than secondDate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with NSDate and NSComparison result stuff for years and I can never for the life of me remember how this works. So I wrote a convenience extension on `Date` for it:

```
func isBefore(_ otherDate: Date) -> Bool {
    let result = self.compare(otherDate)
    switch result {
    case .orderedAscending:
        return true
    case .orderedSame,
         .orderedDescending:
        return false
    }
}
```

If you want to have an `isAfter` extension it just has to return `true` for `orderedDescending`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([startDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"startDate is EARLIER than endDate");
}
```